# How to add color style to text between <% %>

Tags: c#, html, css

I have this code:

```
<span class="title-details">
        <% = (Model.Id == 0 ? Global.NewLocation : Global.EditLocation + " " + Model.Name)%>
</span>
```

How to add different color to part Model.Name ( ex. EditLocation-Black, Model.Name-Blue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split the conditional operator into an if-else statement which would allow you for more fine-grained control over the output:

```
<span class="title-details">
    <% if (Model.Id == 0) { %>
        <%= Global.NewLocation %>
    <% } else { %>
        <%= Global.EditLocation %> 
        <span style="color:Red;">
            <%= Model.Name %>
        </span>
    <% } %>
</span>
```

Comment: I want to add red color on Model.Name but not on Global.EditLocation. Is it possible?

Comment: Of course that it's possible. I have updated my answer to provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
<%= Html.Raw((Model.Id == 0 ? Global.NewLocation : 
                "<font color=\"black\">" + Global.EditLocation + "</font>
                &nbsp;<font color=\"blue\">" + Model.Name + "</font>")) %>
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: -1: this is bad practice. Especially if any of the variables are from user input. Also `<font>` is deprecated since HTML 4.01.

Comment: You know better solution? Please tell me if you do.

Comment: @BertrandMarron, i don't think so its a bad practice in this scenario.

Comment: But @Darin's answer add color to Global.EditLocation and to Model.Name. I need only Model.Name part.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan Then try your code setting `Model.Name`'s value to `<script>while(1){alert('yeah, right');}</script>`.

Comment: @BertrandMarron, you are now splitting the hair

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan This is horrible code, completely unreadable, it uses deprecated HTML tags that are not supported anymore and it makes your application vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: @BertrandMarron, OMG !! its horrible and unreadable. okay i gave which i think the best. try to decide Darin for it.